# Prevent overlap Fullcalendar AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Here is my JS :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxAddEvent.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#newEventForm').serialize() + '&type=1',
    success: function(data) {
         toastr.success('L\'évènement a été créé');
         $('#dialogAdd').dialog('close');
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    },
    error: function() {
         alert('La requête AJAX n\'a pas abouti, contactez l\'administrateur');
    }
});
```

Here is my PHP returning data for AJAX (ajaxAddEvent.php) :

```
//Pour la date de début
$dateTimeStart = new DateTime();
$dateTimeStart = $dateTimeStart->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['startDate']);
$dateStartSQL = $dateTimeStart->format('Y-m-d');

//Pour la date de fin
$dateTimeEnd = new DateTime();
$dateTimeEnd = $dateTimeEnd->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['endDate']);
$dateEndSQL = $dateTimeEnd->format('Y-m-d');

$eventStartSQL = $dateStartSQL . ' ' . $_POST['startHour'];
$eventEndSQL = $dateEndSQL . ' ' . $_POST['endHour'];

$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO event (eventTitle, eventRef, eventStart, eventEnd, calendarID, eventComments) VALUES(:eventTitle, :eventRef, :eventStart, :eventEnd, :calendarID, :eventComments)');
$req->execute(array(
    'eventTitle' => $_POST['title'],
    'eventRef' => $_POST['ref'],
    'eventStart' => $eventStartSQL,
    'eventEnd' => $eventEndSQL,
    'calendarID' => $_POST['type'],
    'eventComments' => $_POST['comments']
));
$req->closeCursor();
```

I know that there is an option in fullCalendar which prevent events from overlapping. But, I use another method for create events, and even with option set as false, the event will be created at the same place as another one.

I would like some help for checking if an event is already existing in database in the PHP file, then I could insert the new event or return data to JS in order to write error message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The obvious thing would be to write a Select statement which checks for events with dates which overlap the dates being added. If you get a result back, then there's an overlap, and you should return an error instead of continuing. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: That is exactly what I am expected for. I am trying to check with SELECT if an event already exists but the problem is that I don't understand how to check if only 15 min or 30 min or the full event is overlapsed.

Comment: can you please post the SELECT query then? We can't fix something we can't see :-)

Comment: OK, I think I found what I wanted. Here is SQL query : 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event WHERE eventStart >= :eventStartSQL AND eventStart < :eventEndSQL'. Then I just have to make actions if 0 or send back err message to js. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should probably be `WHERE eventEnd >= :eventStartSQL AND eventStart < :eventEndSQL` In your version you won't catch any where the event starts earlier but there's still an overlap. Also consider carefully whether you want `<=` / `>=` or just `<` / `>`.

Comment: You are right. It should be : "WHERE eventEnd > :eventStartSQL AND eventStart < :eventEndSQL". I will try now. Thanks a lot.